# Generating RESTful client code IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

When I try to generate a Java RESTful Client with IntelliJ's own option I get a commented main block. I don't know if I'm misusing the tool or if it's just not implemented.

Option under New -> **RESTful Web Service Client**

The code it generates:

```
public class Client {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    // Please, do not remove this line from file template, here invocation of web service will be inserted  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug:

- [IDEA-170486](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170486) RESTful Web Service Client template is blank